# Unit Testing for JavaScript and Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have written a JavaScript library/module that makes API calls to a restful web service and provide methods to the consumers of this library. This library is built in such a way that the same code is used for both as a front end library or as a npm module (converted code using browserify).

However, I now plan to write unit tests for the same and this is the first time I have written an entire library. So, I have looked at libraries like mocha and Jasmine which seems like the good choices for it. I am thinking to write the tests in Mocha. But, I am not quite sure how to start with these tests.

Also, should the tests which test the functionality like a sample consumer be called as integration tests or should those be combined with the unit tests?

I would be happy if anyone can recommend some sample tests on github or some kind of tutorial for a Mocha beginner. I would be happy to consider other unit testing frameworks as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I added a point to this as not sure why people minus points for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking to write the tests in Mocha. But, I am not quite sure how to start with these tests.

**Unit test** usually only includes function test, excluding integration and regression test, which means you should test every functions as possible as you can.

A basic example is like this.

```
function alwaysReturnTrue(){
   return True;
}
assertTrue(alwaysReturnTrue());
```

About unit test framework, such as [mocha](https://mochajs.org/), [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html), they are only for initiating a framework to run your test. Most of them will provide basic `assert` function, such as `assertTrue`, `assertFalse`, `assertEqual`...etc.

Apparently, those assert methods are not enough to test all corner cases.

- callback function
- function called sequence
- function called parameters
- trigger exception
- Fake XHR or Server

For handling those stuffs, it could be completed by a popular solution, which is called [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).

---

> Also, should the tests which test the functionality like a sample consumer be called as integration tests or should those be combined with the unit tests?

No, **Integration test** usually repeat the whole sequence of your software, not a single function. Those thing are also able to be done by sinon. (Fake XHR or Server)

```
For example: without UI
Login() -> Send exit request to serverlet -> Logout()
Login() -> Send exit request with save="true" data to serverlet -> Logout()
```

As I mentioned above, we still have another test which has not been discussed yet. It is called **Regression test** which is the most complex test. There are two famous UI testing libraries to do this, [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html).

```
For example: with UI
Login() -> Click Button Exit() -> Logout()
Login() -> Click Checkbox A() -> Click Button Exit() -> Logout()
```

---

Overall, a completed software testing process have three processes. However, in the real world, time is limited. If your project size is small, than you may skip regression or integration test.

```
step: unit test -> integration test -> regression test
time: (short)      (longer)            (very long)
```